# I18nManager Expo React Native - RTL text - isn't working

Tags: react-native, expo, i18next

I want to make an English / Hebrew application using react native and expo with the text going from LTR or RTL on button click.
I've tried a few ways and the text changes but the direction of the text isn't.

The Code:

```
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import { I18nManager } from "react-native";

// the translations
// (tip move them in a JSON file and import them,
// or even better, manage them separated from your code: https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files)
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      "Hello world": "Welcome to React and react-i18next",
    },
  },
  he: {
    translation: {
      "Hello world": "ברוכים הבאים ל!",
    },
  },
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: I18nManager.isRTL ? "he" : "en", // language to use, more information here: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#languages-namespaces-resources
    // you can use the i18n.changeLanguage function to change the language manually: https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage
    // if you're using a language detector, do not define the lng option

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, I18nManager } from "react-native";
// I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
// I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
import "./src/i18next";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
    I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
    // I18nManager.isRTL(true);
  }, []);

  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{t("Hello world")}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Button
        title="click me!"
        onPress={() => {
          i18n.changeLanguage(i18n.language === "he" ? "en" : "he").then(() => {
            I18nManager.forceRTL(i18n.language === "he");
          });
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

As you can see I've tried different ways to make it work but nothing has. I have restarted the server and it didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Text alignment
The React Native's textDirection property does not accept start or end values that you can use in flex properties. Instead, left effectively works as start (aligns to the left on LTR and to the right on RTL), and right works as end.

However, the default unset value of textDirection property signifies the actual left (aligns to the left both on LTR and RTL).

Because of this, each  tag needs to have the textDirection: left or textDirection: right style set if you want it to be aligned correctly.

It's best to define this style in your custom reusable  component that you can then import everywhere you need to render text strings.this text from expo documentation look that link for more (https://docs.expo.dev/guides/localization/#text-alignment)